# Golang scheduler mystery: Linux vs Mac OS X

Tags: linux, go, concurrency, scheduling

I've run into some mysterious behavior with the Go scheduler, and I'm very curious about what's going on. The gist is that `runtime.Gosched()` doesn't work as expected in Linux unless it is preceded by a `log.Printf()` call, but it works as expected in both cases on OS X. Here's a minimal setup that reproduces the behavior:

The main goroutine sleeps for 1000 periods of 1ms, and after each sleep pushes a dummy message onto another goroutine via a channel. The second goroutine listens for new messages, and every time it gets one it does 10ms of work. So without any `runtime.Gosched()` calls, the program will take 10 seconds to run.

When I add periodic `runtime.Gosched()` calls in the second goroutine, as expected the program runtime shrinks down to 1 second on my Mac. However, when I try running the same program on Ubuntu, it still takes 10 seconds. I made sure to set `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)` in both cases.

Here's where it gets really strange: if I just add a logging statement before the `runtime.Gosched()` calls, then suddenly the program runs in the expected 1 second on Ubuntu as well.

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "log"
    "runtime"
)

func doWork(c chan int) {
    for {
        <-c

        // This outer loop will take ~10ms.
        for j := 0; j < 100 ; j++ {
            // The following block of CPU work takes ~100 microseconds
            for i := 0; i < 300000; i++ {
                _ = i * 17
            }
            // Somehow this print statement saves the day in Ubuntu
            log.Printf("donkey")
            runtime.Gosched()
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    c := make(chan int, 1000)
    go doWork(c)

    start := time.Now().UnixNano()
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)

        // Queue up 10ms of work in the other goroutine, which will backlog
        // this goroutine without runtime.Gosched() calls.
        c <- 0
    }

    // Whole program should take about 1 second to run if the Gosched() calls 
    // work, otherwise 10 seconds.
    log.Printf("Finished in %f seconds.", float64(time.Now().UnixNano() - start) / 1e9)
}
```

Additional details: I'm running go1.10 darwin/amd64, and compiling the linux binary with
`env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build ...`

I've tried a few simple variants:

- Just making a log.Printf() call, without the Gosched()
- Making two calls to Gosched()
- Keeping the Gosched() call but replacing the log.Printf() call to a dummy function call

All of these are ~10x slower than calling log.Printf() and then Gosched().

Any insights would be appreciated! This example is of course very artificial, but the issue came up while writing a websocket broadcast server which led to significantly degraded performance.

EDIT: I got rid of the extraneous bits in my example to make things more transparent. I've discovered that without the print statement, the `runtime.Gosched()` calls are still getting run, it's just that they seem to be delayed by a fixed 5ms, leading to a total runtime of almost exactly 5seconds in the example below, when the program should finish instantaneously (and does on my Mac, or on Ubuntu with the print statement).

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func doWork() {
    for {
        // This print call makes the code run 20x faster
        log.Printf("donkey")

        // Without this line, the program never terminates (as expected). With this line
        // and the print call above it, the program takes <300ms as expected, dominated by
        // the sleep calls in the main goroutine. But without the print statement, it 
        // takes almost exactly 5 seconds.
        runtime.Gosched()
    }
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    go doWork()

    start := time.Now().UnixNano()
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Microsecond)

        runtime.Gosched()
    }

    log.Printf("Finished in %f seconds.", float64(time.Now().UnixNano() - start) / 1e9)
}
```

Comment: You're running into situations that are very unlikely under real-world circumstances - i.e. weird stuff is happening because this is a weird, artificial example that tries to simulate work.

Comment: Actually, this example is contrived because I wanted to isolate the problem, but this behavior came up while I was writing a websocket broadcasting server, and the capacity was ~10x less than expected because of this issue. The rough analogy is that the main goroutine generates messages and pushes them onto the broadcast goroutine, and the work is sending the message to each listening client.

Comment: That's pretty strange, considering that any non-inlined function call causes the current routine to yield to the scheduler. What version of Go is this?

Comment: 1.10. What you just said is surprising, I haven't found that to be the case. The slow function call in my program is WriteMessage() onto a websocket connection, using the gorilla/websocket package. I definitely get different behavior when I interleave the broadcasting WriteMessage() calls with runtime.Gosched().

Comment: The logging statement makes an IO operation, which makes a system call. A system call makes the runtime run the scheduling algorithm.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for the Go issue tracker or mailing list. A quirk or bug in a specific implementation isn't really on topic here.

Comment: But why does runtime.Gosched() alone fail to run the scheduler?

Comment: @rampatowl: Gosched should yield to the scheduler. Something else is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I submitted the question to golang-nuts. In the meantime, I updated this question with more details in case anyone has any ideas!

Comment: @JimB: Have you reproduced this issue on Ubuntu?

Comment: @peterSO, just spun up a 16.04.4 node with go1.10.1, and got similar results to the OP. With only `GoSched()` it is noticeably slower. Adding the `fmt.Println` makes it faster unless stdout is redirected to a file, in which case it reverts to the 6+ second runtime. I'm guessing the new Linux file poller is interfering here somehow

Comment: A couple updates: I updated the original post with a much simpler example showing the weird behavior, without channels or filler work. This example also shows that Gosched() is being called, just with what appears to be a 5ms delay (unless preceded by a print statement). To see if it was an ssh issue, I tried ssh'ing into my Mac from another computer and the program ran fast. Tried another Linux distro (Amazon 4.9.81) and the program was slow.